# Building an Engineer for Multiplayer

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

What would make a good build for engineers in multiplayer. Here's what I'm using so far, let me know what you think.

To tell the truth, it feels like I don't do enough damage right now. I'm finding it hard to kill fast enough so I can stay alive. I am level 18 right now.

I got, Incinerate and Overload maxed out, both set toward AOE'ing. Recently got the Drone to the 3rd skill level, which helped me a lot as a decoy. Got Alliance training to the 5th level toward powers, and fitness to the 2nd.

I'm using the Locust I SMG. Do engineers relie on weapon a lot? Should I be aiming for an Assault Rifle or a Shotgun, and increase my cooldowns?

Thanks

Comment: Engineer, goin' up!

Comment: An upgraded M-8 Avenger seems to have fairly little impact on my cooldowns Maybe 8-9% slower. I think it is the lightest Assault Rifle. It is also effective at medium and long ranges but you aren't precluded from emptying it into an adjacent enemy either. I have yet to play the multiplayer though which is why this isn't part of an answer.

Comment: @Bravo840 unlocking weapons in multiplayer will require a lot of luck/time since it only goes up by 1 rank everytime you get one in a pack, so typically you shouldn't count on having high ranks in any gun unless you play a LOT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paralytic's answer is pretty accurate.  As an engineer, you should not be relying on weapons but on using your tech abilities for maximum damage.  Personally my favorite is the Salarian Engineer, but the following tactics will also work great for the human engineer:

1. Your bread and butter damage skill will be incinerate.   You should be focusing on single target damage rather than AOE with this skill since it is especially effective against armored targets, and the tough enemies all have high armor.  Also, having high damage will let you one shot the usual minions.  A brute should die within 3-4 incinerates if you shoot him with your pistol in between recharges.
2. Energy Drain is an excellent survival tool, allowing you to keep your shields up when under heavy pressure.  Against mostly geth maps, this will be your primary damage dealer, you can easily mop up entire maps spamming this and causing a tech explosion with a incinerate to follow up.  I went with max damage, but if you want survivability the extra armor/shields can also come in handy.
3. You have the perfect tech burst combination in edrain and incinerate.  Even against fleshy enemies, edrain can stun them for several seconds, and it can set up a tech burst if you follow it up with incinerate for a lot of damage.  You don't even have to kill a target for this tech explosion to work, you just have to edrain to shock them then follow it up with a incinerate.
4. I found that 1 point into decoy is plenty.  With extremely fast cooldown, you can keep this up and spam powers none stop with no problem.  Decoy is an excellent skill that can draw a lot of enemy fire.  Even better, its a portable barrier.  If you are facing an geth prime with no cover nearby, putting a decoy between you and the geth prime will mean all his shots won't touch you at all.  Decoy is also great for those situations where you have to camp out in a zone for a long time.  You can easily hold an entire corridor with decoy and some tech explosions, especially against the geth.
5. As a skill spammer, you shouldn't be carrying around a lot of weapons.  A light machine gun and/or pistol should be all you want.  Try to keep your power recharge to as close as 200% as possible.  I go with a good pistol with the scope and damage mod for the guardians (they are the only class that can withstand your powers due to their annoying shield).  Try to head shot them with your pistol.

For human engineers, overload replaces edrain and the drone replaces the decoy, note that the drone does not draw fire, so its not as good for defense, but it can turn guardians around, which is handy.

Finally, for Quarian Engineers, don't underestimate the cryo blast + incinerate explosion combo, it is great crowd control.

My score with a salarian engineer is always the highest in the games due to him being able to handle every tough enemy with ease.

Comment: I really like the Quarian, but Cryo-blast seemed a bit weak compared to Overload. How does it do compared to the 50% upgrade against Armored for Incenate?

Comment: @Allov yea, having cryo blast means you won't have a good way of dealing with shields, which is a bummer.  For armored targets, I'd still prefer incinerate over cryo blast, but doing a cryo explosion can be quite fun.

Comment: @yx good job c: i need to stop rushing my answers and learn from you i think

Comment: @Paralytic still not too late to go back and edit your answer :)  good formatting helps a lot for readability.

Comment: @Paralytic yeah, that's why I upvoted both answer since yours was good too. Just that yx's was a bit more insightful and readable! No hard feelings, keep it up!

Comment: @Allov just to give you an idea of how godly energy drain is, my level 6 got more points than the otehr 3 combined on a geth mission just from edrain and incinerate spam

Answer (score 1):

Max Incinerate and Overload. Do *not* use that useless combat drone, instead max everything else.

Incinerate Spec for +radius and damage over time and +50% armor damage.
Anything with Armor or Health is not happy...

Overload Spec for hit 1 enemy in 8 meters, then cooldown then Shield damage.
Because the "tazer effect" on organics makes them hit the floor, it makes them harder to shoot especially when they are behind cover. Without it they remain standing, so its easy to drill 1/4 mag from a Phaeston in their chest and move on, and having a faster cool-down is obviously good.

Training Weapon damage then Power damage +15% then weapon Damage again.

Fitness Health + shields, then Shield Recharge rate +15% then Health + Shields again.

Nothing this build can't handle, slap on a Phaeston X and go wild...

Answer (score 1):

So, I roll with a human engineer most of the time, and very rarely finish as anything but the highest score, especially in silver and gold matches.  I upgraded incinerate, overload, and combat drone to the max, while putting 5 into N7 operative (or whatever it's called), and 3 into fitness.  Admittedly, this makes this build "softer" than others, but the damage output you get from abilities is absurd.  Some general things about the engineer: as many people have mentioned above, the name of the game is your abilities, and how fast you can use them.  Basically, if you don't have the Carnifex pistol yet, get it.  Now.  No excuses.  It's a headshot machine, doesn't really affect recharge time (you get %160+ recharge speed), and is generally one of the best all-around weapons in the game.  You can roll with the phalanx or the Paladin if need be, but I prefer the Carnifex as a good medium.

Now, I'm gonna assume whoever is reading this played ME1 and ME2, where the Overload ability kind of blew.  Like a lot.  However, if you take the chain lighting-type upgrades plus the upgrade that incapacitates organic enemies for a short while, the engineer becomes one of the best crowd-control classes in the game.  It stuns everyone (the first enemy hit actually falls to the ground or is staggered and takes a knee if they had shields) it hits, including those enemies the overload "jumps" too, and allows you to set up easy headshots, while none of them return fire, so important on higher difficulties, where apparently your shields are based off a butter-like substrate.

Combat drone is great for distractions (why hello, banshee, play with my friend for a while), and should be upgraded to cause massive close-quarters damage (so go for the explosion upon death and the close-range stun move), plus the rocket.  I mean, it's a friggin rocket,it does 400-some damage, has a large radius, etc.  It'll die quickly on higher difficulties, regardless of how much health/shields it has, so make it do what damage it can while it's there.  And I know people hate on the drone, but I can't stress how many times it's saved my ass on silver/gold matches.  Deals a solid chunk of damage while distracting people, thereby setting up further punishment.  And then you can keep.  On.  Spawning it...cause it's recharge time is faster than overload/incinerate.

Incinerate is great against big, boss-type enemies with armor.  Don't take the upgrade to increase radius over damage (remember, overload should be your crowd-control move), and make sure to increase damage against armor by 50% instead of the increased damage to chilled/frozen targets, which relies upon another team mate having cryo blast or someone having cyro ammo.  It's just not worth it.  Also, take the level 5 upgrade for increased damage over time, this'll make you absolutely truck those big obnoxious enemies, and is pretty much what I only use it for, due to a longer recharge time as opposed to overload.

I cannot stress how gnarly this build is, only an asari adept is as good as the engineer in my book (biotic explosions...so unfair).  Furthermore, the salarian engineer is pretty boss as well.  Energy drain = infinite shields, my friends.  However, that being said, the combat drone serves basically the same purpose as the decoy ability...except that is deals out more damage, you can spawn it at any enemy's location on the map (provided that you're locked on to them), and you don't have to deal with return fire...so clutch.

Comment: Yeah, I got myself a second Carnifex not so long ago. But, that kinda answer my question where you ARE weapon dependant, for any class. The only class I can't beat in terms of points is an Infiltrator or two biotics setting up explosions. Still, pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Engineer with a Geth SMG with a scope and a higher damage barrel.

Overload (maxed out) and the insane fire rate from the SMG makes an awesome combination, the SMG weight is VERY light so recharge is massively quick for the overload.

I use the maxed out drone to cover my back or stick it in the middle of my kill zone.

Answer (score 1):

I use the human engineer. I drop my maxed drone near strategic areas to cover me. I use incinerate and overload pretty heavily. I have a geth weapon and a sniper rifle because I like to snipe through guardian mail slots and see through smoke. For banshees or brutes, I sic the drone on them as soon as possible so I can retreat and shoot from cover. Low level drones are good fodder and distractors. Maxed out drones are excellent forward guards.

I'm a RPG player not a MP gal, but sometimes I achieve 1st and 2nd place as an engineer. I've pushed my engineer once to the war front and am working up to a second level. Note: I'm only playing MP for max war assets. Otherwise, I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

On any Tech burst char, always pick single target power boosts over AoE. And on Incinrate Cryo combo chars like the quarian, use an SMG. The only char I'd recommend it on. They can Handel anything without shields well, and there is your shields answer. There racial 6th is even a SMG boost.